# Android studio - Faild to resolve: com.android.support:design:26.0.1 error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have an error called:

```
 "Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:26.0.1".
```

My android studio version is 3.0 beta 1.

My gradle file is as below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "hojune.example"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
}
```

I want to put "design" to my project, but I can't do it. How can I do it?

Comment: Does your project-level `build.gradle` file have both `jcenter()` and `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` in its `allprojects` `dependencies` closure?

Comment: Yes, I changed app-level build.gradle file's com.android.support.design:26.0.1 to com.android.support.design:26.0.0-alpha1. And I solved my problem well.

Comment: August already google release 26.0.1 version, Problem might be you didn't sync properly. may be you could disable **offline mode** and try to sync again. V2.6.0 is [July release check here the latest one](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html)

Comment: Follow instructions from here - https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-migration.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to Change

```
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
```

and

```
com.android.support:design:26.0.0
```

Or not change into bulidToolsVersion Change dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
```

Comment: Please explain, in detail, how this would address the problem. Also, do not use `+` for library version numbers, as then you have no idea exactly what version you are getting, when you need to build this code again in the future (e.g., fixing a bug on a historical branch from version control).

Comment: But I get "Faild to resolve: com.android:support:design-v7:26.+".

Comment: It is not the solution. Why should you use an alpha version while there is a stable version ??

Answer (score 45):

Add this to your project level `build.gradle` file:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
```

Just to clarify, this should be in the "allprojects" section of the gradle file (Thanks to @tys)

Comment: Except where it does not work.  I have Android Studio 2.3.3, am using com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.9.3, and have the Google repository in my maven repositories list as per above -- and still it cannot find the 26.0.1 support libraries.

Comment: Just to clarify, this should be in the "allprojects" section of the gradle file

Comment: Wow! This worked. @JessHolle you need to change the gradle build version. Make it 2.3.3

Comment: As I noted on another question and then forgot to note here, the issue was that @Tys noted, I had this in my buildscript rather than allprojects section -- a subtle but critical difference.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem i solved it by using

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the comment of @Muthukrishnan Rajendran is right google already release 26.0.1 version so a problem in your way of building. 
If you using android studio 3.0 then you need to read this documentation please refer this link https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/05/android-studio-30-canary-1-sdk-updates.html here specified maven.google.com are now available so you need to added below line of code

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

for the above gradle change you need to refer this document https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components.html

also required to change if your project is old

```
dependencies {
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by replacing

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
```

with

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
```

Comment: **Avoid doing this!** Degrading from a stable version to an alpha version is a very bad idea when there is a stable version.